# Texture mapping in OpenGL unexpected error

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping

I tried the code in NeHE tutorial. (http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/)
I download the linux version of the code. (http://codepad.org/ApAyiNuV)
It compiles the code without problem, but when I try to run I get this error:

```
Width of NeHe.bmp: 140204912410880
Height of NeHe.bmp: 140204912410880
Error allocating memory for color-corrected image data
```

Why do I get this error and how can I solve it?(I used gcc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in the code you linked is not related to OpenGL nor is it related to loading images. The problem is, that the way the contents are loaded from the file is unreliable. Take this for example:

```
// read the width
if ((i = fread(&image->sizeX, 4, 1, file)) != 1) {
printf("Error reading width from %s.\n", filename);
return 0;
}
```

The problem here is, that `sizeof(Image::sizeX)` is not neccesarily 4 "chars". The type is `unsigned long` which is *at least* 4 but it can be longer. And it's very likely to be 8 on modern systems. Which means, that 4 of the 8 "chars" are left whatever they already were before the read, which is in the usual care nonzero garbage.

Also the whole endianess issue is not addressed. The only way to implement robust binary loading is by setting all bits explicitly by assignment from a well defined expression. In the case of the field `Image::sizeX` you could write it as

```
char buf[4];
// read the width
if ((i = fread(buf, 4, 1, file)) != 1) {
printf("Error reading width from %s.\n", filename);
return 0;
}
image->sizeX = 
     ((unsigned long)buf[0]) |
    (((unsigned long)buf[1])<<8) |
    (((unsigned long)buf[2])<<16)|
    (((unsigned long)buf[3])<<24);
```

Writing it this way is the *only* way to read binary data in a robust and plattform independent way. Is it tedious to write? Yes, it is. That's why you'd write a number of helper functions to abstract this away.

Comment: It would be solved by using 3rd party library, though. Anyway, `+1` for real problem.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Indeed using a well tested 3rd party library is the recommended approach. But pointing out the actual problem is worthwile. As for what library to use, the opinions differ. Also when developing software you'll sooner than later encounter a situation, where you have to write a binary file parser yourself, for example if you've to process some in-house file format, nobody else uses.

Answer (score 3):

> Important: This way of loading textures is deprecated and does not work anymore with current versions of Visual Studio. The theory of this tutorial is still valid though. An update of the code which is responsible for loading the texture can be found here: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lesson_06_texturing_update/47002/

I believe that linux code you are using is also quite old. Try switching to SOIL or some other image loading library. The updated code should also work on linux.